# Is a list or dictionary faster in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures

How much of a difference are these two as far as performance?

```
tmp = []
tmp.append(True)
print tmp[0]
```

And

```
tmp = {}
tmp[0] = True
print tmp[0]
```

Comment: There isn't much point in this comparision... maybe you can elaborate on your real problem? What is the usage of the data structures?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `timeit` module in the standard library is designed just to answer such questions! Forget the `print` (which would have the nasty side effect of spewing stuff to your terminal;-) and compare:

```
$ python -mtimeit 'tmp=[]; tmp.append(True); x=tmp[0]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.716 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit 'tmp={}; tmp[0]=True; x=tmp[0]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.515 usec per loop
```

So, the dict is the winner -- by 0.2 microseconds...!-)

Comment: Nice. I guess I was worrying over nothing then. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. Dict is faster than list. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 7):

Not only is micro-optimization usually pointless in general, I find it is especially difficult and arcane for Python in particular.  It is very easy to actually make your code simultaneously slower and more complicated.  See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900420/elegant-way-to-compare-sequences) for an example where the simplest, clearest, and shortest Python solutions also turned out to be the fastest.

As others have shown with actual tests, the speed difference between your two choices is quite small.  What is less small is the semantic difference.  Lists and dictionaries are not merely two implementations of the same concept, but are intended for different uses.  Pick the one which better fits your use.

Comment: Well, this particular case I can use either dict or list. The only advantage one may have over the other is performance, hence the question. Well, the dicts are also cleaner looking. It's clear what index is being assigned. I chose the dict but there was this nagging question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that concluded that the dict is the winner is wrong.

Lists are faster than dicts (but not much).

To add items to dicts takes 1.5 x as much time as to lists.

To look up values from dicts takes 1.3 x as much time as from lists.

One should separate the performance for growing the list/dict from the performance of looking up items from the list/dict.

More importantly, the number of elements present might influence the efficiency of adding new elements, especially for dicts.

So, it is better to let the list/dict grow to a big number of elements, and then measure the lookup of all those elements.

Like this

```py
from timeit import timeit
tmpList = []
tmpDict = {}
```

```py
timeListAdd = timeit("""
for i in range(1000000):
    tmpList.append(True)
""", globals=locals(), number=1)
print(timeListAdd)
```

0.08886219099999959

```py
timeDictAdd = timeit("""
for i in range(1000000):
    tmpDict[i]= True
""", globals=locals(), number=1)
print(timeDictAdd)
```

0.1336365199999996

```py
timeListAccess = timeit("""
for i in range(1000000):
    tmpList[i]
""", globals=locals(), number=1)
print(timeListAccess)
```

0.06501517400000001

```py
timeDictAccess = timeit("""
for i in range(1000000):
    tmpDict[i]
""", globals=locals(), number=1)
print(timeDictAccess)
```

0.08099801200000023

By the way, there is a better way to create these structures if you know all the elements at creation time:

```py
timeListCreate = timeit("""tmpList = [True for i in range(1000000)]""", globals=locals(), number=1)
print(timeListCreate)
```

0.03953780500000903

```py
timeDictCreate = timeit("""tmpDict = {i: True for i in range(1000000)}""", globals=locals(), number=1)
print(timeDictCreate)
```

0.0972781530000475

Answer (score -3):

they are equitable in my testing

Comment: If you could provide more information about what you did in your test, that would be great.